# xsl get value of named element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm brand new to xsl so this is probably a very simple question.

I have an xml file as shown below, using xsl how can I get the values of each of the different  elements. I've been trying to use for-each & value-of but cannot seem to get the element value, just keep getting the element names instead.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, that XML is not well formed, so please post the XML you are trying to transform. It would also be worth showing us the XSLT you have tried so we can help you correct it.

In the mean time, this may help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="./elem">
            Value:<xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
            NameAttribute:<xsl:value-of select="@name"/><br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```